# How can i remove local css from jquery accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I used the #accordion jquery method, and in the inspector it shows some local style, and in my html it doesn't appear. The problem is i can't find to root file so i can change it, because it has and height of some px in there, and i want to make the height auto, how can i do that?

I tried searching for solutions everywhere, i tried overwriting in my local html, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="accordion">
                <h3 class="heading">CE ESTE HYALO GYN?<span class="sageata"><i class="  fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></h3>
                <div >
                  <p>
                        HYALO GYN este un tratament vaginal non-hormonal care are la baza Hydeal-D®, 
                        formula special conceputa pentru a reduce rapid si sustinut manifestarile 
                        neplacute ale uscaciunii vaginale si pentru a mentine starea de sanatate vaginala, 
                        indiferent de varsta.
                  </p>
                  <p>
                        HYALO GYN are actiune complexa si un efect de durata, putand fi administrat o data la 3 zile, oricare ar fi cauza uscaciunii vaginale
                  </p>

                </div>
                <h3 class="heading">CE CONTINE HYALO GYN?<span class="sageata"><i class="   fa fa-angle-down"></i></span></h3>
                <div>
                  <p>
                        Componentul principal al HYALO GYN este Hydeal-D®, formula moderna care permite eliberarea prelungita si controlata a acidului hialuronic biologic activ la locul aplicarii.
                  </p>
                  <p>
                        Alte componente sunt propilenglicol, metilpropandiol, carbomer, 1,2-hexandiol, caprililglicol, hidroxid de sodiu, apa purificata.

                  </p>
                  <p>
                        HYALO GYN nu contine hormoni, parabeni sau alte tipuri de conservanti.
                  </p>
                </div>
   </div>
```

HTML that appears in the inspector:

```
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; HEIGHT: 1624px;">
                  <p>
                        Componentul principal al HYALO GYN este Hydeal-D®, formula moderna care permite eliberarea prelungita si controlata a acidului hialuronic biologic activ la locul aplicarii.
                  </p>
                  <p>
                        Alte componente sunt propilenglicol, metilpropandiol, carbomer, 1,2-hexandiol, caprililglicol, hidroxid de sodiu, apa purificata.

                  </p>
                  <p>
                        HYALO GYN nu contine hormoni, parabeni sau alte tipuri de conservanti.
                  </p>
                </div>
```

SOMETHING LIKE that.

As you can see it has and local height of 1624px and i want it to be auto.

How do i do that? where can i find the root file?

Comment: I have no words for on how many levels the post is inadequate. Please provide the  relevant code, as it is impossible for us to know where/what that is. As for vaginal, non-hormonal treatments (what the text is about), you can skip that part.

Comment: @AnduAndrici the OP did provide code, but did not format it properly. I've edited it for them. However it's still not clear exactly what's being asked

Comment: You could try and find the source code for the accordion and change the 'height' property there or you can overwrite the styles ( height ) using your css stylesheet

Comment: can you change your example text to something more ... innocuous?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct height style option on your accordion when you initialise it - by default it will make each panel as tall as the largest panel, if you only want it to be as large as the content, then use the content option:

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle

> heightStyle 
>      Type: String
>      Default: "auto"
>      Controls the height of the accordion and each panel. Possible values:
>
> "auto": All panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel.
>      "fill": Expand to the available height based on the accordion's parent height.
>      "content": Each panel will be only as tall as its content.
>
> Code examples:
>     Initialize the accordion with the heightStyle option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```